# How to get an argument coming from urls.py in views.py

Tags: django, django-class-based-views

So, I'm currently using Class-based views in Django and I have this url dispatcher in my `urls.py`.

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^(?P<store_domainKey>.*)/$', views.StoreDetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
```

and in views.py I wanna get an argument coming from the `store_domainKey`, and it is like the following.

**views.py**

```
class StoreDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Store
    template_name = 'boutique/detail.html'

    def get_queryset(self, store_domainKey):
        store = ???
```

What I wanna do is access `store_domainKey` in my `get_queryset()` function to assign the value in a variable `store`. How can I do that?

**UPDATE**

The reason why I need above is because I'm trying to change my FBV to CBV. I was getting `store_domainKey` from urls.py to views.py by doing the following in my FBV views.

```
def detail(request, store_domainKey):
    store = get_object_or_404(Store, domainKey=store_domainKey)
```

I just wanna do the same thing in my CBV views as well. But, `get_object_or404` doesn't work.

It just throws the following error.

```
TypeError at /downeast/
get_queryset() missing 1 required positional argument: 'store_domainKey'
```

Comment: Not able to understand question, Where you have written last three line? In get function? you can access store_domainKey in get_queryset() function by using self.kwargs['store_domainKey']

Comment: @SHIVAM Sorry for making confusion! the top line from the last three lines was a typo. I updated it now. By the way, I put `store = self.kwargs['store_domainKey']`, but it throws the error saying `get_queryset() missing 1 required positional argument: 'store_domainKey'`

Comment: Your get_quertset function should be 
    def get_queryset(self): 
not 
    def get_queryset(self, store_domainKey):

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below code

```
class StoreDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Store
    template_name = 'boutique/detail.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Store.objects.filter(domainKey=self.kwargs['store_domainKey'])
```

You are getting error because get_queryset does not accept any argument or keword argument.

As your url does not have any pk variable, you should override get_object() method because detail view expect pk argument in url or any argument which it can use as pk.

```
def get_object(self, queryset=None):
    return Store.objects.get(domainKey=self.kwargs['store_domainKey'])
```

Comment: Quick question, like you got a queryset from `Store.objects.filter(domainKey=self.kwargs['store_domainKey'])`, is there a way to get a model object of a store too? I'm asking this because my subsequent codes are based on a model object. So, at the beginning of `get_queryset()`, if I start with a model object instead of a queryset, it would be much more compatible with other codes related to it.

Comment: s = Store.objects.filter(domainKey=self.kwargs['store_domainKey']) it is just a list, you can access s[0], s[1] and so on, But you should use second code of my answer